# What can I do to get my package from Debian unstable to next Ubuntu LTS?

Tags: package-management, lts, debian, release-management

[My package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/thonny) was just accepted into Debian unstable.

There is about 20 days till the feature freeze of next Ubuntu LTS and I'd like to get my package in. Will it get pulled in automatically? Is there anything I can do to make it happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's already done.

Hooray for Ubuntu's [Merge-o-Matic](https://merges.ubuntu.com/)

See https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thonny

Consider spinning up an 18.04 VM, and testing it.

Comment: Whoa! I didn't expect this!
It took 2 months to get from Debian NEW queue to Debian unstable and a few hours from there to Ubuntu :D